# Handle timeout when reading a remote file

Tags: java, file, timeout

I am reading a remote file(xml) that is rendered by a webserver on the fly.Sometimes the webserver takes time to render the remote file.
Sometime there is issue with netowrk and remote url is not reachable
Am using the following code:

```
URL url = new URL(myurl);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
String inputLine;
String strOutput = "";
System.out.println("start now");
//my code hangs after  priting start now    sometime.
//i think in.ready blocks the code flow.
if(in.ready() ){         
  while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
       strOutput = strOutput + inputLine;
  }
}
```

If input stream  is not ready i want my code to continue withoud blocking.How can i handle it?

How can i make sure that my code flow is never blocked indefinately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set time out on the URL connection. See [javadocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setReadTimeout%28int%29).

But you will have to get your stream slightly differently:

```
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
con.setReadTimeout(timeout);
InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
```

Comment: the thing is that the webserver renders the file very slowly .For example when i try to open the file in browser using url i can see that it renders very slowly.Will the code u gave work in that case?

Comment: You have to play with timeout value. It will throw exception if there is no data available for some period of time, but what is this timeout value only you can decide.

Comment: If you use timeout, you probably don't need `in.ready()` as it will block on reading.